# C++: Getting the Current Time as a W3C UTC Time String

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, time, utc

How can I get the current time as a W3C UTC time string as documented at [W3C Date and Time Formats (Profile of ISO 8601)](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)?

Specifically, here is the format I am after:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

Example:

```
2013-05-24T20:07:47Z
```

Note: I am using **Visual Studio 2010**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. Visual Studio 2010 references: [time()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [gmtime_s()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3stkd9be%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

/**
 * Get the current time as a W3C UTC time string.
 *
 * @return A time string; the empty string if something goes wrong.
 */
std::string GetUTCTimeString(void)
{
    time_t seconds_since_the_epoch;
    struct tm tm_struct;
    errno_t err;
    std::ostringstream buf;

    // Return the time as seconds elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970,
    // or -1 in the case of an error.
    time(&seconds_since_the_epoch);

    if (seconds_since_the_epoch == -1) {
        return "";
    }

    // Convert the time in seconds to the time structure.
    err = gmtime_s(&tm_struct, &seconds_since_the_epoch);

    if (err) {
        return "";
    }

    // Format the structure as a W3C UTC date/time string with the special
    // UTC designator 'Z'.
    buf
        <<        std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_year + 1900
        << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_mon + 1
        << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_mday
        << "T" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_hour
        << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_min
        << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tm_struct.tm_sec
        << "Z";

    return buf.str();
}
```